# Как сделать так, чтоб парсеры запускались автоматически в назначенное время?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, парсер

Есть три парсера. Они собирают данные с трех сайтов. Эти парсеры представляют из себя три отдельных файла, которые собирают данные в одну бд. Как сделать так, чтоб они запускались автоматически в заданное время? И можно ли их каким-то образом интегрировать с django-проектом?

Answer (score 1):

С джангой интегрируется [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), там много возможностей запуска задач по расписанию.

Answer (score 0):

Самый очевидный способ - написать [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) и добавить в [крон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) её выполнение в нужное время.