# Способы интеграции парсера на питоне в django

Tags: python, django, парсер

Написал парсер на python'e специально для сайта, все работает, но как его можно теперь объединить? Пробовал через создание экземпляров класса, но модели нормально не импортируются(импортируются, но выдает много ошибок, исправляя которые, все равно возвращает к первой). Поэтому, думаю попробовать использовать две бд(одна для парсинга и выдачи контента, другая для остального функционала). Насколько этот подход оправдан и какие риски могут возникнуть в перспективе? Есть ли какие-то альтернативные способы интеграции?

Comment: Вы уже [спрашивали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/862206/204271).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно написать свою management команду.
Чтобы потом запускать как: `./manage.py ваша_команда`

Подробности тут: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

P.S. - эту команду можно потом добавить в cron/scheduler, чтобы выполнять по расписанию.

P.S.2 - если нужно что-то большее, то стоит подключать Celery и писать бекграунд задачи.